# Differences between JPA and JPA2

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, jpa-2.0

Does anyone have a list of the changes between JPA 1 and JPA 2?
I have read about the Criteria queries and other changes, but I would like a "what's new" kind of reference.
Thanks

Answer (score 31):

[Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=jpa+2+new+features) returns many results, including [this](http://simonmartinelli.blogspot.com/2008/05/new-features-in-jpa-20.html) and [this](http://jazzy.id.au/2008/03/24/jpa_2_0_new_features_part_1.html) blog posts. The summary (copied from the former) is:

- Added support for persistently ordered lists using OrderColumn and provider-managed ordering column
- Defined support for foreign key mapping strategy for unidirectional one-to-many relationships
- Added clear method to EntityManager interface to allow entities to be evicted from the persistence context; added CLEAR cascade option.
- Added Cache interface.
- Added support for pessimistic locking and new lock mode types.
- Added overloaded find and refresh methods added to support locking with standardized and vendor-specific properties and hints.
- Added standardized hint javax.persistence.lock.timeout for use in locking configuration.
- Added the standardized properties javax.persistence.jdbc.driver, javax.persistence.jdbc.url, javax.persistence.jdbc.user, javax.persistence.jdbc.password for use in persistence unit and entity manager factory configuration.
- Added Query getNamedParameters and getPositionalParameters methods.

Comment: Sorting is nicer too, as the @Ordered annotation actually makes the sort on the database side.

Answer (score 9):

JPA2 also adds typesafe query api. see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-typesafejpa/

Answer (score 4):

There is also a pdf version of Mike Keith's presentation "[What's New and Exciting in JPA 2.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20120131141524/http://jazoon.com/portals/0/Content/ArchivWebsite/jazoon.com/jazoon09/download/presentations/8461.pdf)" from Jazoon 2009.

Comment: The link you provides is now down : 404

Comment: @MarcBouvier I have fixed the link to https://web.archive.org/web/20120131141524/http://jazoon.com/portals/0/Content/ArchivWebsite/jazoon.com/jazoon09/download/presentations/8461.pdf

Answer (score 0):

There is a new interface [`javax.persistence.TypedQuery`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/TypedQuery.html) added to control the execution of typed queries.